# iOS UIWebview crash if copy text from the displayed pdf

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

i've tried to search a lot inside stackoverflow and in google before ask my question.
Seems to be similar questions but for me without answer.
So i'm trying to ask!!

i've a view controller presented as presentModalViewController with inside a uitoolbar and a uiwebview.
In the web view is displayed a pdf file. The web view as default allow me to select a text and show to me the copy function of the standard UIMenuController.
At this point if i dismiss the view controller the app crash with this logged error showed in the console:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x372daf68:  teq.w  r0, #0
0x372daf6c:  beq    0x372dafaa               ; objc_msgSend + 66
0x372daf6e:  push.w {r3, r4}
0x372daf72:  ldr    r4, [r0]
0x372daf74:  lsr.w  r9, r1, #2
0x372daf78:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]
0x372daf7a:  add.w  r3, r3, #8
0x372daf7e:  ldr    r12, [r3, #-8]
0x372daf82:  and.w  r9, r9, r12
0x372daf86:  ldr.w  r4, [r3, r9, lsl #2]
0x372daf8a:  teq.w  r4, #0
0x372daf8e:  add.w  r9, r9, #1
0x372daf92:  beq    0x372dafa6               ; objc_msgSend + 62
0x372daf94:  ldr.w  r12, [r4]
0x372daf98:  teq.w  r1, r12
0x372daf9c:  bne    0x372db17e               ; objc_msgSendSuper_stret + 34
0x372daf9e:  ldr.w  r12, [r4, #8]
0x372dafa2:  pop    {r3, r4}
0x372dafa4:  bx     r12
0x372dafa6:  pop    {r3, r4}
0x372dafa8:  b      0x372dafb0               ; objc_msgSend_uncached
0x372dafaa:  mov.w  r1, #0
0x372dafae:  bx     lr
```

I don't understand if this is a my error o a bug of the uiwebview

I've also tried to use CGPDFDocument for render a pdf page but i'm not able to show the UIMenuController and select the text and perform the standard copy action inside the document.
I've also tried to start with this excellent project but also in this i can not perform copy action - https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Basically these are the used code.
I'm working with iOS 5 with ARC

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if (![urlPdfFile hasPrefix:@"http"]) {

NSString *ofType = [urlPdfFile pathExtension];
NSString *pathForResource = [[[urlPdfFile lastPathComponent] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *inDirectory = [urlPdfFile stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pathForResource 
                                                ofType:ofType 
                                           inDirectory:inDirectory];

[self loadCatalogueFile:url];
} else {
[self loadFile:urlPdfFile];
}

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setMyWebView:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {    
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
self.view=nil;
[self viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)loadCatalogueFile:(NSString*)url {

 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
[myWebView loadRequest:request];
}


-(void)loadFile:(NSString*)url
{
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[myWebView loadRequest:request];
}

-(void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
//
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
//
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
//
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: I noticed that if I make a copy of the selected text and then paste the app works correctly and do not crash when i dismiss the view controller. If i select a text or select and copy a text and then dismiss the view controller without any other operation like past the app crash. I hope this could be useful for help me to understand how to solve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Mine was caused because I retained the view controller which holds the UIWebView, and re-used it.
To fix it just create the view controller each time from scratch.